# Calling Stored Procedure w/ Output Parameter within Stored Procedure - Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure that uses an output variable. The stored procedure runs fine, I know that for a fact. I can run the stored procedure using the snippet below

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
    @coEfficientAlpha float

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard]
    @dasId = 4001,
    @keyStandardId = 960,
    @coEfficientAlpha = @coEfficientAlpha OUTPUT

SELECT  @coEfficientAlpha as N'@coEfficientAlpha'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

but when I call this proc from within my other stored procedure, `getTestReliabilityOnDasId`, I receive an

> Invalid Column Name

error message. I'm not doing anything strange within either procedure. Any ideas?

I'll post more code if needed.

Edit:

My code for the 2 stored procedures is below:

Ok, the definition of `getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard` is

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard]
@dasId int,
@keyStandardId int,
@coEfficientAlpha float output
as

--declare @dasId int
--set @dasId = 4001

--declare @keyStandardId int
--set @keyStandardId = 960

-- used all over query
select qa.*, dq.dasQuestionId
into #temp
from test t 
    inner join question q on t.testId = q.testId
    inner join questionAnswer qa on q.questionId = qa.questionId
    inner join dasQuestion dq on t.dasId = dq.dasId and q.questionNumber = dq.questionNumber
    inner join keyStandardDasQuestion ksdq on dq.dasQuestionId = ksdq.dasQuestionId
where t.dasId = @dasId
    and q.questionTypeId = 2
    and ksdq.keyStandardId = @keyStandardId


-- used later in query
select tb1.DasQuestionId, sum(square(tb1.score - tb2.avgScore))/count(tb1.score) as qSd2
into #questions
from #temp tb1
    inner join (
        select questionId, sum(score)/cast(count(score) as float) as avgScore
        from #temp
        group by questionId
    )tb2 on tb1.questionId = tb2.questionId
group by tb1.dasQuestionId

-- used later in query
select studentNo, sum(score) as studentTestScore, count(score) as cntTestScore
into #testData
from #temp
group by studentNo

-- average number of questions correct on test          
declare @avgTScore float
set @avgTScore = (  
    select sum(studentTestScore) / cast(count(studentTestScore) as float) from     #testData    
    )   

-- average variance of questions right on test
declare @tSd2 float
set @tSd2 = (
        select sum(xMinusMean)/count(xMinusMean) as tSd2
        from (
            select (t.studentTestScore - @avgTScore)*(t.studentTestScore - @avgTScore) as xMinusMean
        from #testData t
        )tb1 

    )

set @coEfficientAlpha = (
    select (count(distinct dasQuestionId)/ (cast(count(distinct dasQuestionId) as     float) - 1))*(1-((select sum(qSd2) from #questions)/@tSd2)) as coEfficientAlpha
    from #temp
)

drop table #temp, #questions , #testdata
```

and the definition of `getTestReliabilityOnDasId` is

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getTestReliabilityOnDasId]
@dasId int
as


--declare @dasId int
--set @dasId = 4001

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ks.keyStandardId asc) AS rowNumber,
    da.dasId, da.title, ks.keyStandardId, ks.keyStandardText, count(dq.dasQuestionId)     as countQuestions
into #temp
from districtAssessment da
    inner join dasQuestion dq on da.dasId = dq.dasId
    inner join keyStandardDasQuestion ksdq on dq.dasQuestionId = ksdq.dasQuestionId
    inner join keyStandard ks on ksdq.keyStandardId = ks.keyStandardId
where da.dasId = @dasId
group by da.dasId, da.title, ks.keyStandardId, ks.keyStandardText


create table #KeyStandards(
    [keyStandardId] int,
    coEfficientAlpha float
)

declare @numRows int
select @numRows = max(rowNumber)
from #temp

declare @keyStandardId int, @rowNumber int
set @rowNumber = 1

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @coEfficientAlpha float,
        @numQuestions int

WHILE @rowNumber <= @numRows
BEGIN
    set @keyStandardId = (
   select keyStandardId
   from #temp
   where rowNumber = @rowNumber )

    set @numQuestions = (select countQuestions from #temp where keyStandardId = @keyStandardId   )

    if @numQuestions > 1
    begin
        EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].    [getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard]
                @dasId = @dasId,
                @keyStandardId = @keyStandardId,
            @coEfficientAlpha = @coEfficientAlpha OUTPUT

    end

   insert into #keyStandards
   select @keyStandardId, case when @coEfficientAlpha is null then 'Not Enough     Questions' else @coEfficientAlpha end 

   set @rowNumber = @rowNumber + 1
END

select t.*, k.coEfficientAlpha
from #temp t
    inner join #keyStandards k on t.keyStandardId = k.keyStandardId

drop table #temp, #KeyStandards
```

The exact error message I am getting is:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 33
>   Invalid column name 'questionId'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 31
>   Invalid column name 'questionId'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 31
>   Invalid column name 'score'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 31
>   Invalid column name 'score'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 34
>   Invalid column name 'questionId'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 35
>   Invalid column name 'dasQuestionId'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 27
>   Invalid column name 'DasQuestionId'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 27
>   Invalid column name 'score'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 27
>   Invalid column name 'score'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 41
>   Invalid column name 'studentNo'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 38
>   Invalid column name 'studentNo'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 38
>   Invalid column name 'score'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 38
>   Invalid column name 'score'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 66
>   Invalid column name 'dasQuestionId'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard, Line 66
>   Invalid column name 'dasQuestionId'.

Note: If I run `getTestReliabilityOnDasId` I get these error messages.  If I run `getTestCoEfficientAlphaByDasIdAndKeyStandard` and then run `getTestReliabilityOnDasId` in a separate query window, then everything runs fine. It's almost like the SQL Server engine has to warm up or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a naming collision. Both of them use `SELECT ... INTO` to create a table called `#temp`.

When a stored procedure calls another stored procedure the nested stored procedure can see the temporary tables from the parent.

This pre-existing `#temp` table will have an entirely different set of column names than the sub procedure is referencing and it won't compile.

If you replace all references to `#temp` in one of the procedures with a different temporary table name then you should stop seeing these compilation errors.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, the inner procedure could replace the `SELECT INTO #temp` with `CREATE TABLE #temp` + `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` if using a particular name is obligatory. (Although an obligation of that kind would probably indicate a design problem.)

Comment: @AndriyM - That still wouldn't solve it. The issue would still arise except if the inner proc was compiled first. `EXEC('CREATE PROC P2 AS CREATE TABLE #T(Y INT) SELECT Y FROM #T;');EXEC('CREATE PROC P1 AS CREATE TABLE #T(X INT);EXEC P2');EXEC P1;EXEC P2;DROP PROC P1, P2;`. Though if you reverse the order of the `EXEC` calls it works as it compiles that proc in isolation then just reuses the cached plan when called from the parent proc.

Comment: I believe Martin answered it for me.  Seems to have taken care of it.  Thanks Martin!

Comment: My reply to your comment was nonsensical, sorry. My test was a bit different, because, as I said in my first comment, only the inner procedure used CREATE TABLE, the outer one still used SELECT INTO. At the moment I don't have the SQL Fiddle link to the actual example I was testing, but I think the following edit of your example should be roughly equivalent and indicative of what I mean: `EXEC('CREATE PROC P2 AS CREATE TABLE #T(Y INT) SELECT Y FROM #T;');
EXEC('CREATE PROC P1 AS SELECT 1 AS X INTO #T;EXEC P2');
EXEC P1;
EXEC P2;
DROP PROC P1, P2;` (It works without an error.)

Comment: @MartinSmith, Thanks a lot man!!!!!!!!!!!!! You saved my Day. If it is possible to upvote more than one time, I'll give atleast 100 votes for you.